# how to create a c++ recursive function to return a node custom object?

Tags: c++, c++11, recursion, return-type

how are you?

I created a C++ recursive function in order to iterate over a binary tree and print out all the NODEs where the property **COMPLETED = TRUE**;

It´s working pretty fine because the type of the function is VOID and I am only printing out the result.

This is the way that works fine:

```
void findAndPrintFirstCompletedNodes(treeNode *lastNode) {
     if (lastNode == 0){
         return;
     }
     
   if (lastNode->completed == true) {
          cout << lastNode->word.morseWordElement << endl;
   
   }
      findAndPrintFirstCompletedNodes(lastNode->left);
      findAndPrintFirstCompletedNodes(lastNode->right);
   
 }
```

But what I want to do is to **return** the first found "COMPLETED" **node** instead of just printing!

I tried this way but is not working:

```
treeNode * findAndPrintFirstCompletedNodes(treeNode *lastNode) {
      if (lastNode == 0){
          return 0;
      }
      
    if (lastNode->completed == true) {
           return lastNode;
    
    }
       findAndPrintFirstCompletedNodes(lastNode->left);
       findAndPrintFirstCompletedNodes(lastNode->right);
    
  }
```

Thanks for the help.

Filipe

Comment: You are missing a `return` statement at the end of your "non-working" version. You need to return something there

Comment: I am returning here:

if (lastNode->completed == true) {
           return lastNode;
    
    }

Comment: So what does the function return if that condition is false?....

Comment: At the moment nothing. I want to return a node only if it is completed. I was thinking It is going to call it self till that condition is true. What am I supposed to do?

Comment: @FilipeRebollo A function declared to return something must always return something. It's not optional.

Comment: Thanks Ted, you are right!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem not to be familiar how returning values works.
The result of the lines

```
findAndPrintFirstCompletedNodes(lastNode->left);
findAndPrintFirstCompletedNodes(lastNode->right);
```

is ignored in your code.
Only in the case that the input in the first recursion is completed, anything is returned. Frankly, I wonder why your compiler hasn't warned you.

I think your mistake is that you assume that a return in a recursive call would cause the original call to also return. It doesn't. It produces a value, which is then ignored.
Look at the code below:

```
int four()
{
    return 4;
}

int three()
{
    four();

    return 3;
}
```

What happens in here when you call `three()` is that an integer of value 4 is created, then thrown away, and then the value 3 is returned. `three()` does *not* return 4.

Try this:

```
treeNode * findAndPrintFirstCompletedNodes(treeNode *lastNode) {
    if (lastNode == 0){
        return 0;
    }
  
    if (lastNode->completed == true) {
        return lastNode;
    }

   treeNode* node;

   node = findAndPrintFirstCompletedNodes(lastNode->left);
   if(node) return node;

   node = findAndPrintFirstCompletedNodes(lastNode->right);
   if(node) return node;

   return nullptr;
}
```

In here, I store the return value of the recursive calls in the variable `node`, and return it in case it is not a null pointer, using null pointers as "not found".
In case neither the current node was complete nor anything was found in the recursive calls, I consequently return a null pointer.

You can shorten this to

```
treeNode* node;

node = findAndPrintFirstCompletedNodes(lastNode->left);
if(node) return node;

node = findAndPrintFirstCompletedNodes(lastNode->right);
return node;
```

or even

```
treeNode* node = findAndPrintFirstCompletedNodes(lastNode->left);
if(node) return node;

return findAndPrintFirstCompletedNodes(lastNode->right);
```

but I went with the version above because it should illustrate the point better.

---

By the way, I'd recommend that instead of

```
    if (lastNode == 0){
        return 0;
    }
```

you go with

```
    if (not lastNode){
        return nullptr;
    }
```

or

```
    if (lastNode == nullptr){
```

in order to make clear that we work with pointers.

Comment: Worked!!! Thanks a lot for the response. Looking your code the solution seems to be very simple. I spent 3 days on it though. =(

Comment: @FilipeRebollo Yeah, don't feel bad about spending lots of time on bugs. That is normal. By the way, I edited my answer a few times, consider re-reading it for more info.

Answer (score 1):

Non sure to understand what do you want but I suspect you're looking something as

```
treeNode * findAndPrintFirstCompletedNodes(treeNode *lastNode) {
  if (lastNode == nullptr){
    return nullptr;
  }
      
  if (lastNode->completed == true) {
    return lastNode;
  }

  auto pnt = findAndPrintFirstCompletedNodes(lastNode->left);

  if ( nullptr == pnt ) {
    pnt = findAndPrintFirstCompletedNodes(lastNode->right);
  }

  return pnt;
}
```